# How do i put text under an img icon in a menu?

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm trying to make a menu that looks like this http://i.imgur.com/mWbEYhD.png.

But i end up with a menu like the one like this http://i.imgur.com/DDeEyBr.png.

How do i fix this?

HTML

```
<header>
            <div id="logo">
                <h1>TecQ</h1>
            </div>
            <nav class="prime-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="on" href="index.html"><img src="img/icons/home.png">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a class="on" href="index.html"><img src="img/icons/home.png"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="on" href="index.html"><img src="img/icons/home.png"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="on" href="index.html"><img src="img/icons/home.png"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

CSS

```
.prime-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    }

.prime-menu ul li {
    margin-top: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    }

.prime-menu ul li a{
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #15161c;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 140px; 
    }

.prime-menu ul li a img{
    }

.prime-menu ul li a:hover {
    background: #1c1d25;
    font-weight: 400;
    }
```

Comment: Please add a fiddle to rectify

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by fiddle.

Comment: Add something in JSFIDDLE.net to have an editable working demo. go to JSFIDDLE.net

Comment: @TusharGupta There is no requirement to post a fiddle (www.jsfiddle.net) with every question, especially as the code has been included correctly, which IS a requirement. But here you go.. http://jsfiddle.net/Lw6axfb2/

Comment: I have updated it to look a bit more like the menu: http://jsfiddle.net/Lw6axfb2/8/

Comment: Ok no prob Sorry all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap your text home with `<p>`or `<span>` etc .`<p>Home</p>` and give it `position:absolute;` and use `position:relative;` to `<a>`

[see jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/k6uq77be/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Put `<br>`between your src and text.
Your code will look like this. 
`<header>`
`<div id="logo">` 
 `<h1>TecQ</h1>` 
`</div>` 
`<nav class="prime-menu">` 
 `<ul> <li><a class="on" href="index.html"><img src="img/icons/home.png">Home</a></li>` 
`<li><a class="on" href="index.html"><img src="img/icons/home.png"></a></li>` 
 `<li><a class="on" href="index.html"><img src="img/icons/home.png"></a></li>` 
`<li><a class="on" href="index.html"><img src="img/icons/home.png"></a></li>` 
`</ul>` 
`</nav>` 
`</header>`

Comment: Just wait i'll try it and replay soon

Answer (score 0):

Put your text home in `<p>` like `<p style="position:absolute">Home</p>` and use position:relative; to link `<a>link Name</a>`